# Pi3 startx fails

Tags: raspbian, startx

I'm trying to start the gui on raspbian jessie on a pi 3, using the `startx` command. I get back an error like this:

```
Fatal server error:
Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock
```

and

```
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/pi/.Xauthority
```

I'm quite new to Linux and don't know how to proceed from here. It seems that my /tmp dir is read-only as `touch /tmp/test` returns a message saying that, but if that's the problem I don't know the workaround. Thank you.

Comment: I would guess the xserver is already started. What happens if you press `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`F7`?

Comment: Nothing (tty7 does not exist on my system). I can get to tty2-6, and tty1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1) takes me back to the original prompt (no X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the following command worked to launch X:

```
sudo mount -o remount, rw /
```

If I understand correctly, this gave X access to the /tmp directory that it wanted. Before the filesystem was read-only. Now tty7 is running the desktop properly.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.